# Serilog Eventid is logged as Json

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file, event-id

logger:

```
    ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, "Logging")
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .CreateLogger();
```

settings:

```
  "Logging": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Exceptions", "Serilog", "Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/events.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
          "buffered": true,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:u};{host_ip};{enviroment_hostname};{EventId};{EventCategory};{EventSeverity};{Message:lj};{UserId};{ResourceType};{ResourceId}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithExceptionDetails", "WithProcId", "WithFacility", "ProcessHostEnricher", "WithSeverity" ]
  }
```

In the file I get the following output:

```
2023-01-13 15:43:25Z;;;{ Id: 101 };UserRolesUnAssigned;UserManagement;Medium;User:system roles un-assigned:role1,role2,role3;system;;
```

`{EventId}` comes out as a json object.
I would need just the Id. so `101` instead of `{ Id: 101 }`

EDIT:
LoggerMessageDefinition:

```
private static Action<ILogger, string, string, Exception?> UserRolesUnAssigned =>
    LoggerMessage.Define<string, string>(LogLevel.Information, 101, UserMessageCodes[101].Template);
public static void LogUserRolesUnAssigned(this ILogger logger, string userId, string roleNames)
{
    EventDefinition eventDefinition = UserMessageCodes[101];
    using (LogContext.PushProperty(EventConstants.EventName, eventDefinition.Name))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty(EventConstants.EventCategory, eventDefinition.Category))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty(EventConstants.EventSeverity, eventDefinition.Severity))
        UserRolesUnAssigned(logger,userId, roleNames, null);
}
```

Is there a way to do this out of the box or do I need to create a custom enricher for this?

Comment: I doubt you'd need a custom enricher here. You may be able to [follow the documentation to customize how the object is transformed](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data). Something like `.Destructure.ByTransforming<EventId>(e => e.Id)`

Comment: .Destructure.ByTransforming<> does not affect outputTemplate. Neither EventId nor @EventId does work in the template.